# Can I present a powerpoint presentation with sound?

Tags: sound, openoffice.org, file-format

It is possible to demonstrate .PPT with audio under Ubuntu?
[example such of .ppt - it is short tales for kids](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-Lf32QN-yXBM2Y3M2RiOTEtNTQ0Yi00ZWE3LWI1M2QtNjZlZjYzMjE1Yjhi&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

It should* work, since Ubuntu's Open Office (and the new libre office) have multimedia support. If you have problems with the audio you should add the details to your question.

After trying to playback this file I found a number of problems. Firstly the slide transitions were not actually set. Secondly the media file plays if I manually play it in the editor, but not if I start the slide show (not sure why, but it doesn't load).

I would suggest editing the slideshow in OpenOffice and adding buttons that play back the audio on a click, as well as actually adding slide transition properties (otherwise it will just change the slides rapidly).

BTW - You should not be getting this problem, try recreating the slide show as an impress slide show (just reuse the images etc) and add the details of if it works then to your question.
 - **(I say should instead of will because your question doesn't have the detail of whether you have tried it or not)*

Comment: yes, You are right, I try open attached document but I don't hear any sounds and time interval between slides too shorts... You can try by yourself (see link above)

Comment: ahh Okay I'll test it and see if there is something we are missing :P